# Python: easygui, how to select multiple files?

Tags: python, easygui

I am using fileopenbox() and I want to select all text files I have when the windows box is open. I have tried to press shift or ctrl + A, but it didn't work.

```
openfile = fileopenbox("Welcome", "COPR", filetypes= "*.txt")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can select multiple files if you include *multiple=True* in the arguments:

```
openfiles = fileopenbox("Welcome", "COPR", filetypes= "*.txt", multiple=True)
```

Note that now fileopenbox will return  not a string, but a list of strings like:

["foo.txt", "Hello.txt", "mytxt.txt"]

Comment: `easygui` has been around since at least 2002 and the `fileopenbox()` function in many earlier versions of it don't support a `muliple` keyword argument (although support for it would be easy to add).

Answer (score 2):

another option could be using tkinter as follows(python 3.x):

`import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select files')`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with easygui. What you can do is reuse [the code from easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/sourceforge_site_as_of_2014_11_21/download/version_0.96/doc/epydoc/easygui-pysrc.html#fileopenbox) (see line 1700) and modify it slightly to use `askopenfilenames` instead of `askopenfilename`.